# UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle not showing correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to display some text as a `subtitle` in my `tableView`.

Here's my code for part of the `tableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease]; } //did the subtitle style

        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
        return cell;

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hello there";  //This is not displaying...
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why I'm not seeing the subtitle text when I run?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
return cell;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hello there";  //This is not displaying...
```

You set the `detailTextLabel` after you `return` the cell. When you `return` the cell you leave the method. Therefore the last line of code isn't run.

Comment: Oh duh, that fixed it right away.  Just blew right past me...thanks! :)

Comment: @willingfamily: You should hit Accept on this answer.